# HTML/CSS image reference not working on inline css

Tags: html, css

So i'm trying to set a background image via inline css on a HTML element. For some reason using the path on the src attribute works but the background-image is not found.

This does work:

```
<img src="images/work/1.png" />
```

This does not work:

```
<div style="background: url(images/work/1.png);">image on this element is not visible</div>
```

Using firebug i can see that the image is not found. How is this possible? It is the same url as on the src attribute from the image tag that is found.

Comment: "Using firebug i can see that the image is not found." — It should also tell you exactly what URL is being requested. Compare that for each of the two sets of code. (Wild guess: `<base>` is changing one of them).

Answer (score -1):

This might help
https://jsfiddle.net/mahima154/9ysj8z6y/

```
<div style="background-image: url(/*you image link goes here*/); height:  200px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;"> </div>
```